# Magento Adminhtml Package/Theme (No) Fallback

Tags: magento, themes, package, fallback, adminhtml

Is there any way we could **activate** easily **the fallback hierarchy mechanism** with regards to customized **Admin themes**, as it already exists for the frontend area?

It is not clear where and how this class, **Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package**, used for the 'frontend' area, is instantiated, and I was just wondering if we could rewrite and extend it to make it work for the backend as well.

Currently, copying adminhtml/default/default/ files (both for design and skin folders) to adminhtml/package_name/theme_name and then work on these copied files is not a super clean way, and may become complicated with multiple package(s) and/or theme(s) which each bring only some little changes or improvements compare to default/default. It should fallback, I think.

Ideas, anyone?

Comment: program the fallback if it does not exists jet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug in Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::_fallback. It uses the base package as fallback package for the adminhtml area as well. Instead, it should use the default package because no base package exists for adminhtml. You could create a rewrite for the design package model and modify the _fallback() function:

```
    protected function _fallback($file, array &$params, array $fallbackScheme = array(array()))    
        ...
        $params['_package'] = self::BASE_PACKAGE;
        // otherwise no admin packages with fallback to default package possible
        if ($this->_area == 'adminhtml') {
            $params['_package'] = self::DEFAULT_PACKAGE;
        }
        ...
   }
```

An alternative solution is to simply rename the folder app/design/adminhtml/default to app/design/adminhtml/base. But I don't know what happens if you're updating to a newer magento version then.